# Mouse event in Java

Tags: java, jtable, mouseevent, jlabel

I am trying to move a JComponent say a label over a table.I am tracking this event using MouseMotionListener's mouseDragged method.This method perfectly helps me in tracking the item.Is there a way to track the mouse release after dragging is complete(.ie the dropping event).

```
 tktLabel1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener()
            {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0)
                {
                    tktLabel1.setBounds(tktLabel1.getX() + arg0.getX(),
                            tktLabel1.getY() + arg0.getY(), width, height);

                }

                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
                {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 listeners for mouse events.  The MouseMotionListener which you are already using and the [MouseListener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), which listens for such things as pressed, released etc.

If it is too much of a burden to implement all six methods on this interface you can extend the [MouseAdapter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) instead which provides default no op methods for all the event types and you can just override the ones you need.

**EDIT**

It seems on closer inspection that JList, JTable and JTree [require a bit extra](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html) for drag and drop support.  You will have to implement a [DropTarget](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTarget.html) to be notified of these events.