# MultiDimensional arrays of GRect - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have the following method

```
public void multiArrayGrid(){
    GRect[][] rect = new GRect[3][3];
    int rWidth = 50;
    int rHeight = 50;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            rect[i][i] = new GRect(50,50);
            add(rect[i][i], rWidth+50, rHeight+50);
            rWidth+=50;
        }
        rHeight+=50;
        rWidth = 50;
    }
}
```

The above method is actually making a 3x3 grid of rect.

How do I access, for example, rect[0][0]?

Comment: At what point in the code do you want to access rect[0][0]?

Comment: dope, I hadn't declared rect as an instance variable and was trying to access it from another method. Thanks

Could you please tell me how to make mouseEvents work on rect[i][i]? Thanks

Comment: @user750993 you need to add a mouse listener to your GRect instance, which in this case would be `rect[i][i]`.

Comment: Have a look at [this previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060538/mouse-event-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The code indeed creates a 3x3 grid, but it fills only the main diagonal (0,0), (1,1), (2,2).

To access `rect[0][0]` you simply write exactly this expression, and you will get a `GRect` object or a `null` pointer. To modify a cell you write the same expression, this time on the left side of an assignment operator.

You did try this yourself, didn't you?

Comment: dope, I hadn't declared rect as an instance variable and was trying to access it from another method.

Comment: though, the objective is still no accomplished.

Could you please tell me how to make mouseEvents work on rect[i][i]. Thanks